# Pass a class to a function

Tags: groovy, casting, type-conversion

I want to do something like the following (trivial example):

```
f(Class t, x) { x as t }

int x = f(int, "42")
```

How do I do this in Groovy?

Comment: Is any of the answer appropriate for acceptance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Groovier way will be to use a Closure:

```
f = {Class t, x -> x.asType(t)}

assert f(int, "2") == 2
assert f(float, "2") == 2.0f
assert f(double, "2") == 2.0d
assert f(Integer, "2") == 2
assert f(Long, "2") == 2L
assert f(BigDecimal, "2") == 2G
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are defining f as a method of a class, you could do something like:

```
class F
{
    static <T> T f(Class<T> outputClass, input)
    {
      input.asType(outputClass)
    }
}
```

Then use it by calling

```
F.f(Integer, "42")
```

If you don't care about generics (although they should also help your IDE pick up that the return value is of type T), this also works:

```
class F
{
    static f(Class outputClass, input)
    {
      input.asType(outputClass)
    }
}

assert F.f(Integer, "42").class == Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete your code example :

```
def f(Class t, x) { x.asType(t) }

int x = f(int, "42")
```